# Slope of secant line vs slope at the mid-point

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

I am looking for broad sufficient conditions that allow comparison of $\displaystyle {{f(b)-f(a)}\over {b-a}}$ and $f'\left({{a+b}\over 2}\right)$. As in when $\displaystyle {{f(b)-f(a)}\over {b-a}} > f'\left({{a+b}\over 2}\right)$.
If there are generalizations to higher-order divided differences and derivatives that would be  of interest too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f'(x)$.
$f(b)-f(a)
= \int_a^b g(x)\;dx
$,
$m = \frac{a+b}{2}$,
and
$d = \frac{b-a}{2}$,
so
$\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{2d}
= \dfrac{1}{b-a}\int_a^b g(x)\;dx
$
and

$\begin{align}
D
&=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}-f'(m)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2d}\int_a^b g(x)\;dx-g(m)\\
&= \dfrac{1}{2d}\int_a^b (g(x)-g(m))\;dx\\
\end{align}
$

Let's see what this is for
$g(x) = x^k$,
the standard integrand.

$\begin{align}
D
&= \dfrac{1}{2d}\int_a^b x^k\;dx-m^k\\
&= \dfrac{x^{k+1}}{2d(k+1)}\big|_a^b-m^k\\
&= \dfrac{b^{k+1}-a^{k+1}}{2d(k+1)}-m^k\\
&= \dfrac{b^{k+1}-a^{k+1}}{(b-a)(k+1)}-m^k\\
&= \dfrac{b^{k+1}-a^{k+1}}{(k+1)(b-a)}-\dfrac{(b+a)^k}{2^k}\\
\end{align}
$

If $k=1$,

$\begin{align}
D
&= \dfrac{2(b^2-a^2)-2(b-a)^2}{4(b-a)}\\
&= \dfrac{b^{2}-a^{2}}{(b-a)(2)}-\dfrac{b+a}{2}\\
&= \dfrac{b+a}{2}-\dfrac{b+a}{2}\\
&=0\\
\end{align}
$

If $k=2$,

$\begin{align}
D
&= \dfrac{b^{3}-a^{3}}{(b-a)(3)}-\left(\dfrac{b+a}{2}\right)^2\\
&= \dfrac{b^2+ba+a^2}{3}-\dfrac{(b+a)^2}{4}\\
&= \dfrac{4(b^2+ba+a^2)-3(b^2+2ab+a^2)}{12}\\
&= \dfrac{b^2-2ba+a^2)}{12}\\
&= \dfrac{(b-a)^2}{12}\\
>0\\
\end{align}
$

If $a = 0$ and $k > 1$,

$\begin{align}
D
&=\dfrac{b^{k+1}}{b(k+1)}-\left(\frac{b}{2}\right)^k\\
&=\dfrac{b^{k}}{k+1}-\frac{b^k}{2^k}\\
&=b^{k}\left(\dfrac{1}{k+1}-\dfrac{1}{2^k}\right)\\
&> 0\\
\end{align}
$

If $0 < a < b$ and $k > 1$,
let $x = a/b$.

$\begin{align}
S
&=\dfrac{b^{k+1}-a^{k+1}}{(k+1)(b-a)}\\
&=\dfrac{b^{k+1}(1-x^{k+1})}{(k+1)b(1-x)}\\
&=\dfrac{b^{k}(1-x^{k+1})}{(k+1)(1-x)}\\
\end{align}
$

and

$\begin{align}
m^k
&= \dfrac{(b+a)^k}{2^k}\\
&= \dfrac{b^k(1+x)^k}{2^k}\\
\end{align}
$

We would like to show that,
for $k > 1$ and $0 < x < 1$,
$\dfrac{1-x^{k+1}}{(k+1)(1-x)}
>\dfrac{(1+x)^k}{2^k}
$
or,
if $0 < x < 1$,
$2^k(1-x^{k+1})>(k+1)(1-x)(1+x)^k$,
or
$2^k\sum_{i=0}^k x^i > (k+1)(1+x)^k$.

For $k=2$,
this is
$4(1+x+x^2) > 3(1+2x+x^2)$
or
$1 - 2x + x^2 > 0$
which is true.

Suppose this is true for $k$.
Then,
multiplying by $1+x$,
$\begin{align}
(k+1)(1+x)^{k+1}
&< 2^k(1+x)\sum_{i=0}^k x^i \\
&= 2^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^k x^i+\sum_{i=0}^k x^{i+1}\right) \\
&= 2^k\left(\sum_{i=0}^k x^i+\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} x^{i}\right) \\
&= 2^k\left(1+x^{k+1}+2\sum_{i=1}^k x^i\right) \\
&= 2^k\left(-1-x^{k+1}+2\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} x^i\right) \\
&= -2^k(1+x^{k+1})+2^{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} x^i \\
\end{align}
$

If it is false for $k+1$ and true for $k$,
then

$\begin{align}
(k+2)(1+x)^{k+1}
&\ge 2^{k+1}\sum_{i=0}^{k+1} x^i \\
&>(k+1)(1+x)^{k+1}+2^k(1+x^{k+1})\\
\end{align}
$

or
$(1+x)^{k+1}
>2^k(1+x^{k+1})
$.

We will use Jensen's inequality
to show that
$(1+x)^{k+1}
\le 2^{k}(1+x^{k+1})
$,
so if the inequality is true for $k$,
it is true for $k+1$.

Jensen's inequality states that,
if $h$ is convex and each $a_i > 0$, then

$h\left(\dfrac{\sum a_i x_i}{\sum a_i}\right)
\le \dfrac{\sum a_i h(x_i)}{\sum a_i}
$

Set $h(x) = x^k$,
$x_i = x^i$,
and $a_i = \binom{k}{i}$.
Then
$\sum a_i = \sum \binom{k}{i} = 2^k$,
$\sum a_i x_i = \sum \binom{k}{i} x^i
= (1+x)^k$,
so Jensen becomes
$h\left(\dfrac{(1+x)^k}{2^k}\right)
\le \dfrac{\sum a_i h(x_i)}{\sum a_i}
$
or
$\left(\dfrac{(1+x)^k}{2^k}\right)^k
\le \dfrac{\sum \binom{k}{i} x^{ik}}{2^k}
\le \dfrac{(1+x^k)^k}{2^k}
$
or
$\dfrac{(1+x)^k}{2^k}
\le \dfrac{1+x^k}{2}
$
or
$(1+x)^k
\le 2^{k-1}(1+x^k)
$.

Putting $k+1$ for $k$,
this is
$(1+x)^{k+1}
\le 2^{k}(1+x^{k+1})
$.

Comment: You are right. I will see if I can fix it up. If not, I will insert a big "oops!".

Comment: In my update, I show that it is true for $f'(x) = x^k$ for $k > 1$ and $0 \le a < b$.

Comment: Thanks. Nice proof. I could figure the first few cases but the general case stumped me!